# Anuglar-animate. 1.2.9 uncaught object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

I've an running an web application with angular.js (1.2.9)

i want to extend it with some animation stuff.

For this i i referenced the ng-animate js-file:

```
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ng/restangular.js"></script>
```

and I extended my module creation with ng-animate

```
var crApp = angular.module('crApp', ['ng-animate','restangular', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router'])
```

but from then on i got a "uncaught object" error without changing anything else.

[image: Screenshot]

For me this looks like the ng-animate module could not be resolved.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var crApp = angular.module('crApp', ['ngAnimate','restangular', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router'])
```

Edit: The problem for the author was that he spelled 'ngAnimate' incorrectly, and thus the module could not be loaded.

Comment: Explaining what and *why* you've changed will not only help the OP but future readers, too. Thanks.

Comment: That solved. don't know why i used ng-Animate instread of ngAnimate. ans also just didn't realized it till your post. thx